# jQuery: set value of table cell inside div

Tags: jquery

I have a floating div which contains a title and I want to change that title. I tried this:

```
$("div#dragTitle3").text("New Title");
```

But the title is actually in a table inside the div. This is the table:

```
<table><tbody><tr><td>Announcements</td><td style="text-align:right"><img src="buttontop.png" class="divTitleButton" id="dragButton3" onmousedown="javascript:toggleContentWin(3)"></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

I want to know how I can change the title without entering the whole table's code when I set the new table.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should work:

```
$("div#dragTitle3 td:first").text("New title")
```