# Passing value from textbox to partial view without model MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

I have a view and inside that a partialview. When I submit my form the action ShowDetail works perfectly and shows in a table like it should. There's just one thing, I want to first row to be empty except for one cell (the one with id="startvalue"). If i just type in some value inside the td-tag it works fine. But I want the value from @Html.TextBox("PresentValue").

I have tried with some JQUERY but it didn't work and it kind a blocked my other JS-functions (don't know why)..

So my question is if I possible can take the value from @Html.TextBox("PresentValue") and send it into  on submitting a form?

The jQuery I tried:

```
$(document).on('click', '#test', function() 
{
  var startValue = $("#PresentValue");
  $("#startvalue").Append(startValue);
}
```

My Controller:

```
public ActionResult ShowDetail(FormCollection form)
{
  List<Calculation> cList = new List<Calculation>();
  Calculation calc = new Calculation();
  calc.Date = Convert.ToDateTime(form["startdate"]);
  calc.InvoiceAmount = 2000;
  calc.InterestRate = Convert.ToDouble(form["InterestRate"]);
  calc.InterestAmount = (Convert.ToDouble(form["PresentValue"]) * Convert.ToDouble(form["InterestRate"]) / 360 * 30);
  calc.Amortization = (2000 - (Convert.ToDouble(form["PresentValue"]) * Convert.ToDouble(form["InterestRate"]) / 360 * 30));
  calc.PresentValue = Convert.ToDouble(form["PresentValue"]) - calc.Amortization;
  cList.Add(calc);
  for (int i = 0; i < Convert.ToInt32(form["PaymentPeriods"]); i++)
  {
    Calculation calcBefore = cList.Last();
    calc = new Calculation();
    calc.Date = calcBefore.Date.AddMonths(1);
    calc.InvoiceAmount = 2000;
    calc.InterestRate = Convert.ToDouble(form["InterestRate"]);
    calc.InterestAmount = (calcBefore.PresentValue * Convert.ToDouble(form["InterestRate"]) / 360 * 30);
    calc.Amortization = (calc.InvoiceAmount - (calcBefore.PresentValue * calc.InterestRate / 360 * 30));
    calc.PresentValue = calcBefore.PresentValue - calc.Amortization;
    cList.Add(calc);
  }
  return PartialView("ShowDetail", cList);
}
```

My PartialView:

```
<tr>
  <td align="center">
  </td>
  <td align="center">
  </td>
  <td align="center">
  </td>
  <td align="center">
  </td>
  <td align="center">
  </td>
  <td align="center" id="startValue">
    //Here do I want the value from @Html.Textbox("PresentValue")
  </td>
</tr>
@foreach (var item in Model) 
{
  <tr>
    <td align="center">
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)
    </td>
    <td align="center">
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InvoiceAmount)
    </td>
    <td align="center">
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InterestRate)
    </td>
    <td align="center">
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InterestAmount)
    </td>
    <td align="center">
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Amortization)
    </td>
    <td align="center">
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PresentValue)
    </td>
  </tr>
}
```

In my View (inside a BeginForm):

```
@Html.TextBox("PresentValue")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your jquery snippet to something like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#test', function() 
{
  var startValue = $("#PresentValue").val();
  $("#startvalue").text(startValue);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Can it be because when the form submits it goes directly to ShowDetail() in the controller?

Comment: If I try: $(document).on('click', '#test', function () {
    var startValue = $("#PresentValue");
    alert(startValue);
});, the alert says Object object instead of the value

Comment: Yes, but if you do alert(startValue.val()) it should state the value.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
  var startValue = $("#PresentValue").val();
  $("#startvalue").text(startValue);
}
```

Comment: var startValue = $("#PresentValue").val(); gives me the right value. But $("#startvalue").html(startValue); doesn't write it into the table. I tried with text() and Append() as well

Comment: .text(startValue) should work @krillezzz check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/937950/jquery-set-value-of-table-cell-inside-div

Comment: $(document).on('click', '#ButtonID', function () {
    var startValue = $("#PresentValue").val();
    $("#startValue").text(startValue);
}); is not working @Nitin Varpe

Comment: Possible it's different because its a partialview?

Comment: then i think there is no value for startValue  is empty i.e null. Check whats value of $("#PresentValue")

Comment: alert($("#PresentValue").val()); gives me the output I want

Comment: really cant get it now, are both elements on same page. does $('#startvalue') exists on page

Comment: The $("#startvalue") exists on a partialview (not the same page where I get $("#PresentValue").val() )

Comment: $(document).on('click', '#ButtonID', function () {
    alert($("#PresentValue").val());
    var startValue = $("#PresentValue").val();
    $("#startValue").text(startValue);
});  With input 100 with this code first I get alert with 100, and then nothing changes with #startValue

Comment: Is it possible because its a partialview ?

Comment: i dont think because browser renders all elements on single page

Comment: I've tried to put all this on the same page, and then it works fine

Comment: i think $("#startvalue")  did not exist on page. it doesnt matter if you render number of partial view on page . you can access value from anywhere using jquery. if that exist in html